# Making an Int increase every second by x value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game similar to the 2013 style Cookie Clicker. I'm stuck with making the auto generate over time script. I want to be able to access a script that makes "Muffins" automatically.

I've tried to make the script multiple times but I can't seem to get the muffin count to change.

```
    public bool MakingMuffins = false;
    public static int MuffinIncrease = 1;
    public int InternalIncrease;

    void Update () {
        InternalIncrease = MuffinIncrease;
        if (MakingMuffins == false)
        {
            MakingMuffins = true;
            StartCoroutine(MakeTheMuffin());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator MakeTheMuffin ()
    {
            GlobalMuffins.MuffinCount += InternalIncrease;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            MakingMuffins = false;

    }
}
```

and my other main file to start the method.

```
public void StartAutoMuffin()
    {
        if (InternalPlayerMuffins >=bakerycost){
        playSound.Play();
        StartBakery.SetActive(true);
        InternalPlayerMuffins -= bakerycost;
        bakerycost *= 2;
        turnOffButton = true;
        themps += 1;
        thelevel += 1;
        }else{
            Debug.Log("Cant do anything");
        }
    }
```

StartBakery is a Game Object that should start the auto make after I press the button. It is set inactive as default.

Here is more code from my main script to help understand.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GlobalGameMechanics : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool turnOffButton = false;
    public AudioSource muffinSound;
    public AudioSource playSound;
    public static int GlobalPlayerDiamonds;
    public int InternalPlayerDiamonds = 1200;
    public GameObject PlayerDiamondDisplay;
    public GameObject TotalMPS;
    public GameObject Cost;
    public GameObject Level;
    public GameObject MPS;
    public GameObject FakeCost;
    public GameObject FakeLevel;
    public GameObject FakeMPS;
    public int InternalPlayerMuffins = 15;
    public int bakerycost = 25;
    public int thelevel = 0;
    public int themps = 0;
    public int currentMuffins;
    public GameObject ShopPanel;
    public GameObject fakeButton;
    public GameObject realButton;
    public GameObject StartBakery;


    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {

       GlobalPlayerDiamonds = InternalPlayerDiamonds;
       PlayerDiamondDisplay.GetComponent<Text>().text = "" + InternalPlayerDiamonds;
       TotalMPS.GetComponent<Text>().text = "/Sec " + themps;

       GlobalMuffins.MuffinCount = InternalPlayerMuffins;
       Cost.GetComponent<Text>().text = "" + bakerycost;
       Level.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Level " + thelevel;
       MPS.GetComponent<Text>().text = "MPS " + themps;

       FakeCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = "" + bakerycost;
       FakeLevel.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Level " + thelevel;
       FakeMPS.GetComponent<Text>().text = "MPS " + themps;

        currentMuffins = InternalPlayerMuffins;
        if (currentMuffins >= bakerycost)
        {
            fakeButton.SetActive(false);
            realButton.SetActive(true);
        }
        if (turnOffButton == true)
        {
            realButton.SetActive(false);
            fakeButton.SetActive(true);
            turnOffButton = false;
        }

     }
```

So far I have created 1 button that I want to increase the "InternalPlayerMuffins" By 1 every second. And then I want to have Button 2 to increase by +5 /sec. I'm just having trouble and been stuck for a few days.

I cant make the muffins increase at all on its :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are close, it seems like you forgot to loop your coroutine endlessly like so:

```
IEnumerator MakeTheMuffin() {
    while (true) {
        GlobalMuffins.MuffinCount += InternalIncrease;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        MakingMuffins = false;
    }
}
```

Though I may be wrong on that, since I am not so sure if `GlobalMuffins.MuffinCount` is the integer that you want to increase every second.

But generally the idea is the same, you want would want a coroutine, a target interval, a target integer and the value you want to increase by, like so:

```
public class YourMuffinMaker : MonoBehaviour {
    public float intervals;

    public int increment;

    private int muffinCount;

    void Start() {
        muffinCount = 0;
        StartCoroutine(CreateMuffinEveryIntervals());
    }

    private IEnumerator CreateMuffinEveryIntervals() {
        while (true) {
            muffinCount += increment;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(intervals);
        }
    }
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58254401/7421086) answer that was posted is an alternative to Coroutine as well.

Answer (score 0):

i can use [InvokerRepeating](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html) whick calls method every time u need, for example

```
void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("CreateNewMuffin", 0f, 1f);
}
```